# mongodb Join two collections to get data

Tags: php, mongodb

So here is my attempt it did not work, I am not sure what I need to do, and the docs explaining this are just confessing.

so I am hoping someone on here knows how to do this.

Basic concept: I have stored the users latest profile picture ID in the users main profile collection

members collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("aaaat656a464"),
    "email" : "russell@ipet.xyz",
    "personal" : {
        "name" : {
            "firstname" : "Russell",
            "lastname" : "Harrower"
        },
        "profile_id" : ObjectId("333a0e2b7acebe9b869b1b0a")
    },
    "kst" : ObjectId("111111111111g")
}
```

Now I want to get that profile_id from members_media collection which _id = profile_id

This is the members_media collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("333a0e2b7acebe9b869b1b0a"),
    "data" : {
        "url" : "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/11659354_1625058617782022_7822649569017662262_n.jpg?oh=6e2b74b33c1c4ea4cdc0094a1ae35e14&oe=59DF809A",
        "type" : "facebook/image",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-06-21T06:16:18.580Z"),
        "profile_pic" : true
    },
    "uid" : ObjectId("111111111111g")
}
```

So here is my attempt

```
$check = $db->aggregate([
                        ['$unwind'=> "$members_media"],
                        ['$unwind' => ['path'=>"$members_media",  'includeArrayIndex'=>"arrayIndex"]],
                        ['$lookup'=>
                            [
                              'from'=>"members_media",
                              'localField'=>"personal.profile_id",
                              'foreignField'=>"_id",
                              'as'=>"profilepic"
                            ]
                        ]



                ]);
```

However when I run the following it does not get the members collection

```
$db = static::db()->members;
    /*$check = $db->findOne(['kst' => New MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($_SESSION["ipet_user"]), 'personal'=>['$exists'=>true]],
                       ['personal.profile_id' => 1]
    );*/

    $check = $db->aggregate([
                    ['$lookup' =>


    [
                      'from'=>"members_media",
                      'localField'=>"members.personal.profile_id",
                      'foreignField'=>"_id",
                      'as'=>"data"
                    ]
                ],
                ['$match' => 
                   ['members.kst' => New MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($_SESSION["user"]), 'members.personal'=>['$exists'=>true]]
                ],
                ['$unwind' => ['path' => '$members_media.data', 'includeArrayIndex' => 'arrayIndex']],
                ['$project' =>
                    ['members.profile_path'=>'$data.url']
                ]

        ]);
```

my result is

```
object(MongoDB\Driver\Cursor)#19 (9) { ["database"]=> string(4) "ipet" ["collection"]=> NULL ["query"]=> NULL ["command"]=> object(MongoDB\Driver\Command)#18 (1)
```

Comment: Are you positive about the collection names? Have you tried running in the shell first? Because I think you should. This is really confusing since you have two attempts doing two different things. The `$unwind` statements certainly have no place at the top of the aggregation pipeline. The second looks closest to viable. But you really should be testing this in stages, and at least have some idea if you have the correct collection names or not. Right now, it does not look convincing that you have tested thoroughly. Please tell us more.

Answer (score 0):

We can do like this

```
$resultData = $db->collectionName->aggregate([

                  ['$lookup' => [ 
                      'from' => 'members_media',  
                      'localField' => 'personal.profile_id',
                      'foreignField'  =>  '_id',
                      'as'  => 'profileDetail',
                   ]]]);

 $myData = array();

    foreach($resultData as $result) {
      //var_dump($result);
      array_push($myData, $result);
    }
    print_r($myData);
```